# How use json in php with a 'complex' structure?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i want use json + php for my data. I read more document to do this, and the basic function are json_decode() and json_encode(). My problem is that, read more document and read different example of structure have created in me a lot of doubts.

I want create a structure like this begine from the basic to the container:

- there is a Base, that have 2 property: id and value
- there is a Operations that can have multiple Base
- there is a Command that can have multiple Operations (and if possible a property callad name)

the structure in my mind is like this...

```
[ //The start of Commands

  //Can make a property name here like "name":"puls1"
  [ //Operation1
 { //Base1
   "id":"22398",
   "value":"255"
 },
 { //Base2
   "id":"22657",
   "value":"80",
 },
 { //Base3
   "id":"7928",
   "valore":"15"
 }
  ],

  [ //Operation2
 { //Base1
   "id":"22398",
   "value":"0"
 },
 { //Base2
   "id":"22657",
   "value":"0",
 },
 { //Base3
   "id":"7928",
   "valore":"0"
 }
  ],

] //The close of Commands
```

But i have put the [ and { in the not correct order i think...
How can i make a json structure like this? And after set a command to insert a new Operation or remove Operation?

Thank's at all..

//Ok by answer of i made this code

```
class Base 
{
  var $i;
  var $value;

  function __construct($i,$v) 
  {
   $this->id = $i;
   $this->value = $v;
   }
}

$a = new Base('1','11');
$b = new Base('2','10');
$c = new Base ('3','20');
$d = new Base ('4','30');

class Operation
{
  var $name;
  var $values = Array();

  function __construct($a) 
  {
   $this->name = $a;
  }

  public function addArray($a)
  {
   array_push($this->values,$a);
  } 
}

$oper1 = new Operation("op1");
$oper1->addArray($a);
$oper1->addArray($b);

$oper2= new Operation("op2");
$oper2->addArray($c);
$oper2->addArray($d);

$commands = Array($oper1,$oper2);

echo json_encode($tot);
```

Now the problem is how can i make the revert operation? Such a use of json_decode and incapsulate in its appropriate structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with PHP I would construct the objects from native PHP Classes (json_encode works with php objects as well):

```
class Base {
    var $id;
    var $value;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of putting these objects in various arrays, which you can also abstract with methods like `addToOperation($baseObj)` and `addToCommands($operationObj)`.

You're dealing with native data structures ([Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)), so you can use native methods to remove (array_pop) and add (array_push) data.

Comment: With your code i try this class Base 
 {
   var $id;
   var $value;
 
   function __construct($i,$v) 
   {
  $this->id = $i;
  $this->value = $v;
   }
 }
 
 $a = new Base('1','11');
 $b = new Base('2','10');
 
 
 $commans1 = Array($a,$b);
 $commans2 = Array($a,$b);
 
 $tot = Array($commans1,$commans2);
 
 echo json_encode($tot);


How can i add a property name to the operations?

Answer (score 5):

The json list type `[]` is equal to a array without keys in php.

The json dictionary type `{}`is equal to a keyed array in php.

What you want is something like this:

```
$json = array(
   array(
     array('id' => $num, 'value' => $val), // Base 1
     array('id' => $num_1, 'value' => $val_1), // Base 3
     array('id' => $num_2, 'value' => $val_2), // Base 2
   ),
   array(...),
   array(...),
);
```

Comment: Very nice this code...if i want get a value a can use $json[0][0]->id; Only a question is there a way to add a property to the array(...) in my case to the operations?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
// Build up your data as a mulitdimensional array
$data = array(
    'operations' => array(
        0 => array(
           'bases' => array (
            0 => array(
                'id' => '22398',
                 'value' => 'whatever'
            ),
            1 => array(
                'id' => 'id goes here',
                 'value' => 'value goes here'
            ),
         1 => array(
            //data for operation 2
         )
);

// Then use json_encode
$json = json_encode($data);
```

My syntax may not be perfect but that should give you the idea. To access it then you would use code like

```
 $operations = json_decode($data);
 foreach ($operations as $op) {
     foreach ($op->bases as $base) {
         //Logic goes here
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but i want a complete example of manager that structure...for example how can i add another Commands?

Comment: just put commands above everything else $data = array('commands' => array(0 => array). I think that that is the best managment that you can come up with

Comment: If you want to give the command a name you can add name before the operations as a property of the commands. Think of your structure as a multidimensional array, build that array and use json_encode is the best technique for complex data.